# (idempotent)Does $rank(A) + rank(A-I_n)=n$ implies $A^2=A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, projection-matrices, idempotents

> Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(R).$  If $rank(A) +rank(A-I_{n})=n$, show that $trace(A)=rank(A)$

I have already known that an idempotent $A^2=A$ implies...$$(1)rank(A) +rank(A-I_{n})=n\qquad(2)trace(A)=rank(A)$$
But the original question is as above.

Does $rank(A) + rank(A-I_n)=n$ implies $A^2=A$ so that I can consequently prove that $trace(A)=rank(A)$ ? Or $rank(A) + rank(A-I_n)=n$ can directly implies that $trace(A)=rank(A)$ even without the condition that $A^2=A$???

Comment: Please add the definition of $I_n$